# Laravel 5.8 how to include node_modules

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, node-modules, laravel-5.8

I need to include [tempusdominus datetimepicker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/) to my Laravel 5.8 project but I am no able to load the scipts and styles correctly.

According documentation I tried to add this lines to my bootstrap.js.

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    mix.copy('node_modules/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css', 'public/css/tempusdominus.css');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('moment');
    require('tempusdominus-bootstrap-4');

    require('./main.js');
} catch (e) {}
```

Watcher says everything was compiled successfully but console throws me an error **$(...).datetimepicker is not a function** and I dont see any tempusdominus css in the public directory.

The script with $().datetimepicker is included via section at the very end of the file this way.

```
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'sk'
            });
            $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'sk'
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a typo "ode_modules"

Comment: Yes but it is not the reason. I fixed it.

Comment: Try wrapping the modules in require like `require(["bootstrap","moment","tempusdominus-bootstrap-4"], function(){ require('./main.js'); })`

Comment: Why? Jquery and main.js are loaded correctly. What is the difference?

Comment: It is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, install Bootstrap 4 and the Tempus Dominus package with NPM.

```
npm i bootstrap
npm i tempusdominus/bootstrap-4
```

You should see '`tempusdominus-bootstrap-4@5.1.2`' in your [package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/package.json) file.

Add this in your [app.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/resources/js/app.js) file:

```js
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.TempusDominusBootstrap4 = require('tempusdominus-bootstrap-4');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

Then for the CSS add this to your [app.scss](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/resources/sass/app.scss):

```
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

@import '~tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/src/sass/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4';
```

Then compile your assets:

```
npm run prod
```

You should be in business now but don't forget this somewhere in your JS...

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(FUNCTION)
```